# What is the command for Enabling diagnostic logs on Azure AD with PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-diagnostics

I am preparing an script that enables Diagnostics logs sending them to an Storage Account.

```
Get-AzureRmResource | foreach {  
    #For now adding all registered resources to Diagnostics Logs. Should narrow to specific resource types?
    #Categories "Execution", "Request" only, the "AllMetrics" category intended to log all categories fail. Can add specific categories to each resource type.
    Write-Output "Adding resource $_.ResourceId to the storage"
    Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $_.ResourceId -StorageAccountId $storageid -Enabled $true -RetentionEnabled $true -RetentionInDays 90 -Categories “Execution”,“Request”
}
```

This PowerShell command matches to enable the Diagnostics Logs to the resources created within the Subscription.

What about to enable the Diagnostigs Logs in Azure Active Directory? They include Audit and Sign-In logs?

Can someone please adivice?

Many thanks!

Sergio

**Update:**
I am required to automate the following with PowerShell:
1. Go to Azure Portal 
2. On the left blade, select Azure Active Directory 
3. Select Audit Logs or Sign-In logs 4. On the top Menu, select Export Data Settings
5.Click Add diagnostic setting 
6. Check Archive to Storage Account and Set Retention days. 
Process described in video: 
[Video discussing Azure AD reports shows how to enable the Logs, I am required to automate enabling the logs, not getting the report](https://www.youtube.com/embed/syT-9KNfug8?start=84)

Answer (score 1):

MSOL offers these log / audit resources.

> Collect and consume log data from your Azure resources
>
> Azure Monitor diagnostic logs are logs emitted by an Azure service
>   that provide rich, frequent data about the operation of that service.
>   Azure Monitor makes available two types of diagnostic logs:
>
> • Tenant logs - these logs come from tenant-level services that exist
>   outside of an Azure subscription, such as Azure Active Directory logs.
>
> • Resource logs - these logs come from Azure services that deploy
>   resources within an Azure subscription, such as Network Security
>   Groups or Storage Accounts.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs
>
> Azure Active Directory Audit logs
>
> Audit events currently provided from the management portal are also
>   downloadable per documentation at Azure Active Directory Audit Report
>   Events. It is now convenient for an admin of an organization to gather
>   critical changes that are happening in their Azure Active Directory
>   tenant.
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresecurity/2015/06/11/azure-active-directory-audit-logs

What other logs are you trying to enable beyond the above?

What are you after?

Note: AAD is not ADDS from a diagnostics approach perspective.

***Update for OP***

> Audit Logs for Azure Events
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2015/03/10/audit-logs-for-azure-events/
>
> Retrieving Resource Metrics and Creating Alert Rules via Azure
>   PowerShell
>
> Metric Definitions
>
> The Get-AzureRmMetric cmdlet downloads the definitions of an Azure
>   Insights metric. For example, the following retrieves the definitions
>   for a VM named myVM in a resource group named myRG:

```
$resourceId = '/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_guid/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM'

Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition –ResourceId $resourceId `
 -DetailedOutput
```

> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/02/26/retrieving-resource-metrics-and-creating-alert-rules-via-azure-powershell

```
Example 4: Get all resources with a given name

PowerShell ＝ Copy  （ Try It 
PS C:\> Get-AzureRmResource -Name testVM | fl

Name              : testVM
ResourceGroupName : testRG
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
Location          : westus
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testVM


Example 7: Get a resource by resource id

PowerShell ＝ Copy  （ Try It 
PS C:\> Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testVM

Name              : testVM
ResourceGroupName : testRG
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
Location          : westus
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testVM
```

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.7.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer @postanote . I'm after the AAD audit and sign-in logs. They're the ones shown on the video inserted here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/overview-activity-logs-in-azure-monitor As seen, in Azure Portal they enter the AAD node and then they enable Audit and Sign-in logs. I want to automate this. On your first link, in the PowerShell syntax on section "Enable collection of resource diagnostic logs via PowerShell" they use ResourceId param. When I query for RM resources, I do not get AD resourceIds, so there should be another way.

Comment: See my update for you. Are you saying, that you've reviewed these and they are not giving you what you are after?

Comment: Thanks for update. Exactly, I've reviewed this before coming here. I understand the use of the Get-AzureRmResource and Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting cmdlets. Question is how to get an Azure AD Resource ID to invoke the Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting cmdlet, or if there is a different PowerShell cmdlet to enable Diagnostic logging for Azure AD. On exec Get-AzureRmResource with context set to my Azure AD tenant, I do not get Azure AD resources. In the description of Diagnostics Logs Overview exists distiction between Tenant Logs and Resource logs, they do not address Tenant Logs in the article.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it seems that there is **no** powershell command to get the Azure AD Audit and Sign-In logs **directly**.

If  Micorsoft Graph Rest API is acceptable, you could use the following  [Microsoft graph Rest API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/azure_ad_auditlog_overview) to do that.

```
GET tenant user activities  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits
```

---

```
GET tenant user sign-ins    https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns
```

We also could get the demo code from this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Pull-Azure-AD-Audit-Report-ae78ecaa). 
If we want to run the code. We need to do prerequisites to access the Azure Active Directory reporting API, for more information please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-configure-prerequisites-for-reporting-api).

```
$URIfilter = "?`$filter=activityDateTime gt $PastPeriod"  
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits" + $URIfilter 
GetReport $url "DirectoryAudits" $Tenantdomain
```

For more information about Azure AD report, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/overview-reports)

**Update:**

We could use the following Rest API to enable/update the Azure Audit logs or Sign-In logs.

```
Put https://management.azure.com/providers/microsoft.aadiam/diagnosticSettings/{name}?api-version=2017-04-01-preview
```

Body

```
{
  "properties": {
    "logs": [
      {
        "category": "AuditLogs",
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 0,
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "SignInLogs",
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "days": 0,
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "metrics": [],
    "storageAccountId": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourgroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageAccountName}"
  }
```

**I test it with postman.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tom Sun .Question is not how to get / to obtain / to pull Azure AD Audit and Sign-In logs.Question is about how to enable these logs with PowerShell, so they are available, i.e. in an Storage Account.  Steps to automate in Azure portal terms are: 1. Go to Azure Portal 2. On the left blade, select Azure Active Directory 3. Select Audit Logs or Sign-In logs 4. On the top Menu, select Export Data Settings, 5.Click Add diagnostic setting 6. Check Archive to Storage Account and Set Retention days. Process described in video: https://www.youtube.com/embed/syT-9KNfug8?start=84

Comment: we could create or update the logs with following rest API `https://management.azure.com/providers/microsoft.aadiam/diagnosticSettings/{name}?api-version=2017-04-01-preview` I also  have updated the answer with detail information

Comment: Hi, tom, if I call the api `https://management.azure.com/providers/microsoft.aadiam/diagnosticSettings/write` with a service principal, what permission should the sp have? A similiar issue need your help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666223/azure-permissions-over-microsoft-aadiam-diagnosticsettings-write ;-)

Comment: @JoyWang If application permission is not working.  Have you tried to use the user permission? And please also try to use the  global admins user

Comment: @TomSun just came across this here, I'm the OP on the other post. I've also got a support ticket open with Microsoft and they also can't get the API call working that apparently worked for you.
My SP has Global Administrator permissions on the AAD tenant and Owner permissions on the subscription the Log Analytics workspace is in.
I get an "unauthorized" error as described in the other post.

Comment: @TomSun can you let me know what permissions your SPN has? On the tenant and the subscription.
Also, did you retrieve the Bearer token calling this API?

`BEARER_TOKEN=$(curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F" https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token | jq -r .access_token)`

Comment: @DavidO'Brien  I have added the detail steps on this [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666223/azure-permissions-over-microsoft-aadiam-diagnosticsettings-write)