# Getting/Deleting Azure Entra ID Diagnostic Settings using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to check the Diagnostic Settings I have in Azure Entra ID and delete them when necessary using PowerShell. The Diagnostic Settings can be seen in Azure portal -> Entra ID -> Diagnostic Settings. Those DSs look to me that are not related to any resource and can not be manipulated the same way the resource-specific DSs are handled.

Just to be clear, I am not speaking about resource-specific Diagnostic Settings, those can be retrieved/deleted using `Get/Remove-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId <ResourceId>` cmdlet.

I am asking this question because I am deploying some subscription-scoped Diagnostic Settings that become part of the Entra ID Diagnostic Settings page and that has a limit of 5 diagnostic settings only, so I am reaching that limit quite quickly. I want a way to check whether I have reached that limit for Entra ID and delete some of them when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created Diagnostic settings for sample in ***Azure portal -> Entra ID -> Diagnostic Setting*** like below:

[image]

To **fetch the count of the Microsoft Entra ID Diagnostic Settings**, make use of below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-AzAccount

# Generate an access token for the management API
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com").Token

# Set the API endpoint 
$apiEndpoint = "https://management.azure.com/providers/microsoft.aadiam/diagnosticSettings?api-version=2017-04-01-preview"

# Set the headers for the API call
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiEndpoint -Headers $headers -Method Get

$count = $response.value.Count
$output = $response.value | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

Write-Output "count : $count"
Write-Output "value : $output"
```

[image]

To **delete the Microsoft Entra ID Diagnostic Settings**, modify the script like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount

# Generate an access token for the management API
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com").Token

# Set the API endpoint 
$apiEndpoint = "https://management.azure.com/providers/microsoft.aadiam/diagnosticSettings/ruk?api-version=2017-04-01-preview"

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiEndpoint -Headers $headers -Method Delete
Write-Output "Diagnostic setting deleted successfully."
```

[image]

*When checked in the Portal, the Microsoft Entra ID Diagnostic Setting is deleted successfully:*

[image]

**Reference:**

[What is the command for Enabling diagnostic logs on Azure AD with PowerShell? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866634/what-is-the-command-for-enabling-diagnostic-logs-on-azure-ad-with-powershell) by Tom Sun

Comment: It's a good alternative using the Rest API. I was all the time reading the docs searching for a powerShell cmd but it seems not available.

Comment: Yes AFAIK there is no direct command